# Blocking in a background thread in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, backgroundworker, block, manualresetevent

I am working with Windows Phone's Coding4Fun toolkit's MessagePrompt object.  I want to display the MessagePrompt and then block or wait until the MessagePrompt's Completed event fires.  I obviously want to do this in a background thread as I don't want to block the main UI thread.  I have been playing with this for a bit, I have hooked up an ManualResetEvent with a BackgroundWorker but it doesn't seem to wait.  What's the best way to implement something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't block UI thread you can use activity Indicator till messagebox is showing.

Comment: I don't want nor plan to block the UI thread.  As stated, I want to show the messagebox in a background worker. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use this piece of code..Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    messageBox.show();
                });

Comment: if working then tell me else I will see your problem tomorrow.